# How to compute AUC and generate ROC curve for RNN and LSTM models using Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am running RNN and LSTM models using a custome pre-defined function `trainDNN`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import fully_connected
import h5py
import time
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
def trainDNN(path, n_days, n_features, n_neurons, 
            train_sequences, train_lengths, train_y,
            test_sequences, test_y, test_lengths,
            lstm=False, n_epochs=50, batch_size=256,
            learning_rate=0.0003, TRAIN_REC=8, TEST_REC=8):
    # we're doing binary classification
    n_outputs = 2

    # this is the initial learning rate
    # adam optimzer decays the learning rate automatically
#     learning_rate = 0.0001
    #learning rate decay is determined by epsilon
    epsilon = 0.001

    # setup the graph
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    # inputs to the network
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_days, n_features])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
    seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

    # the network itself
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons) if lstm else tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seq_length)
    logits = fully_connected(states[-1] if lstm else states, n_outputs)

    # the training process (minimize loss) including the training operatin itself
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=epsilon)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    # hold onto the accuracy for the logwriter
    correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

    # this saves the network for later querying
    # currently only saves after all epochs are complete
    # but we could for example save checkpoints on a
    # regular basis
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # this is where we save the log files for tensorboard
    now = int(time.time())
    name = 'lstm' if lstm else 'rnn'
    root_logdir = path+"tensorflow_logs/{}/{}-{}/".format(name.upper(), name, now)
    train_logdir = "{}train".format(root_logdir)
    eval_logdir = "{}eval".format(root_logdir)
    print('train_logdir', train_logdir)
    print('eval_logdir', eval_logdir)

    # scalars that are written to the log files
    loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
    acc_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)

    # summary operation and writer for the training data
    train_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([loss_summary, acc_summary])
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(train_logdir, tf.get_default_graph())
    # summary operation and writer for the validation data
    eval_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([loss_summary, acc_summary])
    eval_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(eval_logdir, tf.get_default_graph())

    # initialize variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    n_batches = len(train_sequences) // batch_size
    print(n_batches, 'batches of size', batch_size, n_epochs, 'epochs,', n_neurons, 'neurons')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # actually run the initialization
        init.run()
        start_time = time.time()
        for epoch in range(n_epochs):
            # at the beginning of each epoch, shuffle the training data
            train_sequences, train_y, train_lengths = shuffle(train_sequences, train_y, train_lengths)
            for iteration in range(n_batches):

                # extract the batch of training data for this iteration
                start = iteration*batch_size
                end = start+batch_size
                X_batch = train_sequences[start:end]
                y_batch = train_y[start:end]
                y_batch = y_batch.ravel()
                seq_length_batch = train_lengths[start:end]

                # every TRAIN_REC steps, save a summary of training accuracy & loss
                if iteration % TRAIN_REC == 0:
                    train_summary_str = train_summary_op.eval(
                        feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
                    )
                    step = epoch * n_batches + iteration
                    train_writer.add_summary(train_summary_str, step)
                    # without this flush, tensorboard isn't always current
                    train_writer.flush()

                # every TEST_REC steps, save a summary of validation accuracy & loss
                # TODO: this runs all validation data at once. if validation is
                # sufficiently large, this will fail. better would be to either
                # pick a random subset of validation data, or even better, run
                # validation in multiple batches and save the validation accuracy 
                # & loss based on the aggregation of all of the validation batches.
                if iteration % TEST_REC == 0:
                    summary_str = eval_summary_op.eval(
                        feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y.ravel(), seq_length: test_lengths}
                    )
                    step = epoch * n_batches + iteration
                    eval_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
                    # without this flush, tensorboard isn't always current
                    eval_writer.flush()

                # run training.
                # this is where the network learns.
                sess.run(
                    training_op,
                    feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
                )

            # after every epoch, calculate the accuracy of the last seen training batch 
            acc_train = accuracy.eval(
                feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
            )
            # after each epoch, calculate the accuracy of the test data
            acc_test = accuracy.eval(
                feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y.ravel(), seq_length: test_lengths}
            )

            # print the training & validation accuracy to the console
            print(epoch, time.strftime('%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), "Accuracy train:", acc_train, "test:", acc_test)


        # save the model (for more training or inference) after all
        # training is complete
        save_path = saver.save(sess, root_logdir+"model_final.ckpt")

        # close the writers
        train_writer.close()
        eval_writer.close()    
        log(["{}-{} model score".format(name.upper(), now), percent(acc_test)])
```

The function above trains RNN and LSTM model on time sequence data and outputs a binary classification score. The train and test scores are printed, but I am trying to figure out how to compute AUC and generate ROC curve for the binary classification of RNN and LSTM.

**UPDATE:**

I evaluated the logits and predictions using the following script:

```
n_epochs = 2
batch_size = 2000
n_batches = len(train_sequences) // batch_size
print(n_batches)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    #sess.run( tf.local_variables_initializer() )
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        train_sequences, train_y, train_lengths = shuffle(train_sequences, train_y, train_lengths)
        for iteration in range(n_batches):
            start = iteration*batch_size
            end = start+batch_size
            X_batch = train_sequences[start:end]
            y_batch = train_y[start:end]
            seq_length_batch = train_lengths[start:end]
            if iteration % 20 == 0:
                train_summary_str = train_summary_op.eval(
                    feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
                )
                step = epoch * n_batches + iteration
            if iteration % 200 == 0:
                summary_str = eval_summary_op.eval(
                    feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y, seq_length: test_lengths}
                )
                step = epoch * n_batches + iteration
            sess.run(
                training_op,
                feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
            )

        acc_train = accuracy.eval(
            feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
        )
        acc_test = accuracy.eval(
            feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y, seq_length: test_lengths}
        )
        probs = logits.eval(feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y, seq_length: test_lengths})
        predictions = correct.eval(feed_dict = {logits:probs, y: test_y})
        print(epoch, "Train accuracy:", acc_train, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)# "Manual score:", score)
```

This returns me probs which is basically a matrix with rows equal to number of test cases and 2 columns containing probability for each of the 2 binary classes. The predictions object contains whether the prediction was correct or not. 
I am sceptical because ReLU function probability scores are not as intuitive as sigmoid function scores because its no more based on a default 0.5 cut-off for positive and negative predictions. Rather, the prediction is based on which class has more probability. Is it really possible to generate ROC curves from ReLu outputs?

Answer (score 2):

Please note the `tf.metrics.auc()` mentioned below is obsolete. There is [`tf.compat.v1.metrics.auc`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/metrics/auc) as a drop-in substitute, but even that is deprecated now, and the recommendation is to use [`tf.keras.metrics.AUC`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC). Sorry, don't have time to refactor the code below.

---

You can use `tf.metrics.auc()` for this purpose. Please note you need the one-hot encoded labels and the predictions for this, and you also need to run the `update_op` it returns if you're trying to accumulate the AUC over multiple `sess.run()` commands, see separate section below.

In your code, you create `y_one_hot` with [`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot), and you'd put all this right after `accuracy` maybe:

```
y_one_hot = tf.one_hot( y, n_outputs )
auc, auc_update_op = tf.metrics.auc( y_one_hot, logits )
```

Before you start the training loop, you need to initialize the local variables auc creates as well, maybe right after `init.run()`:

```
sess.run( tf.initialize_local_variables() )
```

and then when you run the accuracy, you also need to run the `auc` with `accuracy` in `sess.run()` instead of `.eval()` like this (untested):

```
# after every epoch, calculate the accuracy of the last seen training batch 
acc_train, auc_val = sess.run( [ accuracy, auc ],
    feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
)
# after each epoch, calculate the accuracy of the test data
acc_test, auc_val = sess.run( [ accuracy, auc ],
    feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y.ravel(), seq_length: test_lengths}
)
```

---

### Accumulation over multiple batches

If you do want to use the accumulation feature of `tf.metrics.auc()` then you also need to take care of resetting the accumulation once you want to start a new calculation. For that to happen, you need to collect the local variables created. So create the auc like this:

```
with tf.variable_scope( "AUC" ):
    auc, auc_update_op = tf.metrics.auc( predictions=y_pred, labels=y_true, curve = 'ROC' )
auc_variables = [ v for v in tf.local_variables() if v.name.startswith( "AUC" ) ]
auc_reset_op = tf.initialize_variables( auc_variables )
```

And when you're done with accumulation, reset the internal variables of auc like this:

```
session.run( auc_reset_op )
```

And you also need to make sure to run the `auc_update_op` each time you run `sess.run()` like this:

```
# after every epoch, calculate the accuracy of the last seen training batch 
acc_train, auc_val, _ = sess.run( [ accuracy, auc, auc_update_op ],
    feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch}
)
session.run( auc_reset_op ) # maybe you want to do this here...
# after each epoch, calculate the accuracy of the test data
acc_test, auc_val, _ = sess.run( [ accuracy, auc, auc_update_op ],
    feed_dict = {X: test_sequences, y: test_y.ravel(), seq_length: test_lengths}
)
```

Comment: Why are you using `logits` to compute AUC? In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc) it explicitly says that predictions are a floating point Tensor of arbitrary shape and whose values are in the range [0, 1] which are scaled version of logits.

Comment: Hi Arat, this was a while back, can't remember exactly, but this was more about how to use `tf.metrics.auc` than the network itself. Having now reviewed his code, you might be right that the variable _logits_ is not the right one to use. Please note in my code example I used _y_pred_ as variable name as, again, I focused on the usage of `tf.metrics.auc`, creating, updating, and resetting the variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaination, Peter! Yes, you are right! I missed that. I just saw there is an information pollution about how to compute AUC and wanted to point it out!

Comment: dead link in there

Comment: @jtlz2 added prefix to answer explaining that tf.metrics.auc got removed and what to use instead.